# What it means for a Jacobian determinant to be zero in the context of PDEs and their solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The book mentioned that if the Jacobian determinant is zero then no solution exists in the neighbourhood of the boundary curves.
What does this means in simplified terms? What are boundary curves? I might be familiar with what boundary curves means if a list of possible terminology could be listed.

Comment: This web site could help you : 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238221/how-to-find-the-boundary-curve-of-a-surface-like-the-möbius-strip

Comment: What book? Solution of which equation? There's not enough context in this question.